How to speed up a code which uses FindRoot in a plot?
I have the following Mathematica code:
f[r_] := ((25 - 1/r^2)^(2/3) (25 + 1/r^2)^(1/3)
   r^2 (-24 - r^2 + 25 r^4))/(-25 + 625 r^2)



h[r_] := ((25 - 1/r^2)^(2/3) (25 + 1/r^2)^(1/3)
   r (24 + 4207 r^2 - 150 r^4 - 8125 r^6 + 187500 r^8))/(
 75 (1 - 25 r^2)^2 (1 + 25 r^2))



V[r_, x_, k_] := 
 k^2/(1 + 24/(r^2 - 25 r^4)) + 4 (1 + 1/(25 r^2))^(2/3) r^4 x^2

delyb[r_] := E^Sqrt[f[r]]/(2 f[r]) ((Sqrt[f[r]] f'[r])/2 - h[r])

Veff[r_, x_, k_] := 
 V[r, x, k] - (E^Sqrt[f[r]] delyb'[r] - (delyb[r])^2) // Simplify

s1[r_] := NIntegrate[1/ Exp[Sqrt[f[\[Chi]]]], {\[Chi], 0, r}]

r[s_?NumericQ] := 
 r1 /. FindRoot[Re[s1[r1]] == s, {r1, 0.5}, Evaluated -> False]

p = Plot3D[
  Evaluate[Re[Veff[r[s], x, 4]]], {s, 0.01, 0.7}, {x, -10, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> All]

It has been running for 30 minutes on my PC without giving any plot. Is there a better way by which I can speed up the computation and also get rid of the excessive warning messages?
Any help in this regard would be truly beneficial!

Not really sure yet about speeding up, but it might be worth noting that f[r] has a discontinuity at r=1/5 so it may be worth only looking up to r = 1/5 instead of 0.5

r is used as function  and parameter, dangerous!!!

@UlrichNeumann Why should this be dangerous?

I think the problem is that r involves an expensive solve and is used in Veff[r[s], x, 4] in the plot. So for every value of x, the value of r[s] has to be computed again. I recommend to evaluate r on a sufficiently fine grid and to generate a less expensive InterpolationFunction with Interpolate.

This needs less than half a minute on my 16-core computer:
f[r_] := ((25 - 1/r^2)^(2/3)*(25 + 1/r^2)^(1/3)*
     r^2*(-24 - r^2 + 25*r^4))/(-25 + 625*r^2);
h[r_] := ((25 - 1/r^2)^(2/3)*(25 + 1/r^2)^(1/3)*
     r*(24 + 4207*r^2 - 150*r^4 - 8125*r^6 + 
       187500*r^8))/(75*(1 - 25*r^2)^2*(1 + 25*r^2));
V[r_, x_, k_] := 
  k^2/(1 + 24/(r^2 - 25*r^4)) + 4*(1 + 1/(25*r^2))^(2/3)*r^4*x^2;
delyb[r_] = (E^
      Sqrt[f[r]]*((1/2)*Sqrt[f[r]]*Derivative[1][f][r] - h[r]))/(2*
     f[r]);
Veff[r_, x_, k_] = 
  V[r, x, k] - (E^Sqrt[f[r]] delyb'[r] - (delyb[r])^2) // Simplify;
s1[r_] := 
 NIntegrate[1/Exp[Sqrt[f[\[Chi]]]], {\[Chi], 0, r}, 
  Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
r[s_?NumericQ] := 
 r1 /. FindRoot[Re[s1[r1]] == s, {r1, 0.5}, Evaluated -> False, 
   Method -> "Secant"]
AbsoluteTiming[
 vals = Flatten[
   ParallelTable[{s, x, Re[Veff[r[s], x, 4]]}, {s, 0.01, 
     0.71, .1}, {x, -10, 10, 1}], 1]; 
 ListPlot3D[vals, PlotRange -> All]]


Suppose I wish to increase the data points by taking {s, 0.01, 0.71, 0.01}; shall I use MaxInterations -> Infinity to achieve the goal?

It seems to be necessary to lower the precision and accuracy, rather than changing MaxIterations.
So specifying the FindRoot options
PrecisionGoal -> 4, AccuracyGoal -> 4  allows to finish with {s, 0.01, 0.71, 0.01} in about 90 seconds.

Thank you for the much needed help :)

Can you help me with NDEigensystem as well as I asked here?

Sorry, no. No time.
